PHP PDO ODBC getColumnMeta: native_type is missing in result array
I need to find out the column type of columns in a query:
$columnmeta = $stmt->getColumnMeta($column);
In the resulting array the native_type is missing, there is only pdo_type, which is pretty much useless since PDO seems to treat everything as a string.
In the manual it is stated "Warning:Some drivers may not implement PDOStatement::getColumnMeta(), as it is optional. However, all PDO drivers documented in the manual implement this function."
Since ODBC is documented, this should be there...is there something I can do about it? Or is there a different way to find out the column type?
Thanks in advance!

Which database are you using? Did you try direct ODBC calls and odbc_field_type()?

Relatively unknown database, ElevateDB. odbc_field_type() works.
